# ProxyTable doen't work in vuejs when call api

Tags: api, vue.js, url, proxy, frontend

In config/index.js i config like this

```
proxyTable: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:44322',
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    },
```

And this code i call get method.

```
<template>
<div>
  <ul v-if="posts && posts.length">
    <li v-for="post of posts" v-bind:key="post.employeeId">
      <p><strong>{{post.firstName}}</strong></p>
      <p>{{post.lastName}}</p>
      <p>{{post.phoneNumber}}</p>
      <p>{{post.dateOfBirth}}</p>
      <p>{{post.email}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul v-if="errors && errors.length">
    <li v-for="error of errors" v-bind:key="error.id">
      {{error.message}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'Axios',
  data () {
    return {
      posts: [],
      errors: []
    }
  },

  // Fetches posts when the component is created.
  created () {
    Axios.get('/api/employee')
      .then(response => {
      // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
        this.posts = response.data
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
        console.log(e)
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

I want when i call

```
http://localhost:8080/#/axios
```

the client call to backend :

```
http://localhost:44322/api/employee
```

But nothing happen, i see in header of request the url is :

```
localhost:8080
```

i do flow the link of vuejs: https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html ,part API Proxying During Development. Any idea for this?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you would see the request url as `http://localhost:8080/api/employee` in the browser

and finally the request will be transferd to `http://localhost: 44322/api/employee` which you won't see in network panel of your browser